# When the two transactions occur at the same time, what would the result be

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I'm learning MySQL and have a newbie question:

Transaction 1:

```
update Log set status=2
balabala
```

Transaction 2:

```
update Log set status=1
balabala
```

Assuming when the transaction 1 runs, the 2 comes, and what would the result be? And, is the @Transactional in springboot the same to the transaction in MySQL?

Comment: It depends on what is read, how the update is done etc. The `@Transactional` will start a transaction on the resource in use, in your case MySQL.